# "Popular to" someone or "popular with" someone?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english

> - The teacher is popular to his student
> - The teacher is popular with his student

Which one is correct & why?

Comment: Welcome to ELU; I've improved the title of your question to be more explicit about the actual question. I suspect the downvotes are because there is no evidence of any prior research here. What have you found in your own efforts to answer this question? (Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/346787/edit) that research in)

Answer (score 1):

Both are wrong. Being "popular" is a statistical property of a group. It means that the majority of members of a group have a positive opinion. So a teacher can be popular with his *students*, but not with just one student (and in this case, "with" is the proper word.)